# How can I add my iOS device in apple developer page?

Tags: ios, certificate

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

The webpage above is what I have referenced. This page says as follows:

To register an App ID

1. Sign in to developer.apple.com/account, and click Certificates, IDs & Profiles.
2. Under Identifiers, select App IDs.
3. Click the Add button (+) in the upper-right corner.
4. Enter a name or description for the App ID in the Description field.

But what the page looks like is this:

[image]

There's no such thing like 'Certificates, IDs & Profiles' or something like that. So I clicked my profile on the top right; then moved to 'Manage Your apple ID' page.

[image]

[image]

I don't think this 'device' tap is what I am looking for.. The reference shows this screenshot but I couldn't find this anywhere.

[image]

So what page should I go to keep going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, however it looks like you aren't logged in to a paid developer account since it says "Join the Apple Developer Program" at the bottom. You need to have a paid account in order to add devices to the developer console at developer.apple.com.

If you are using a free account, you can install an app for 7 days to your device by adding your account details to XCode. Just go to Preferences -> Accounts.

Once you have access to a paid account in the program, come back to developer.apple.com and you will see more options. Click on "Certificates, IDs & Profiles":

[image]

Then from the next page click on "All" under "Devices":

[image: Devices - All]

Then finally, click on the "+" icon in the top right to add a new device:

[image: Add Device]

EDIT: updated to include information about installing an app on device for free accounts

Comment: If you have a free account you can add apps to one device for 7 days at a time. Xcode does this for you; you need to add your developer account into the Xcode preferences.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - edited to include information about installing on device for free accounts and to clarify that you cannot add devices to the dev console with a free account.